# Changing form select field with Mechanize not working (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, forms, mechanize

I'm trying to use mechanize to submit a form by changing input for a "select" field. However, when I change the input value and submit, it is returning the page as if no fields were changed.

Also on any field in this form except this one I get the right page back. Why would this be happening? Is there a way to use mechanize to actually "select" the right option in the select field?

```
#This is how I set up my browser
br = Mechanize.new
cert_store = OpenSSL::X509::Store.new
cert_store.add_file 'cacert.pem'
br.cert_store = cert_store
page = br.open(url)
form = page.forms.first

#I've tried
form["sel_subj"] = "ACCT"
new_page = form.submit

#and 

form.field_with(:name => "sel_subj").options[1].select #and ".click"
new_page = form.submit
```

I get no error message, and no "404" page not found, so it must be finding that particular form option. It's just not showing the page that it would if I manually selected that option on chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the select box was multi-select, and "clicking" on an option added it without unselecting the previous option.

Changing:

```
search_form.field_with(:id => 'subj_id').options[i].click
```

To:

```
search_form.field_with(:id => 'subj_id').options[i].click
search_form.field_with(:id => 'subj_id').options[i+1].click
```

Did the trick, hence clicking on the previously selected option.